# Hide folder from other users in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, user-profiles

Is there a way we can have user specific folders in XP that other users cannot access or use?. Thanx
**edit:**I have my drives in fat32 filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It must be on an NTFS partition. Right click the folder, select properties, security. Remove permissions for everyone, then add Full Control for just the users that should access the folder. You may have to disable inheritance in the Advanced screen. [More on permissions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308419).

Comment: Thanx, I have everything fat32 formatted.. Is there anyway we can do this for fat32 filesystems.

Comment: Fat32 does not support security or file permissions. You're only option is to convert the file system to NTFS.

Comment: converted to ntfs, Thanx